# Nesting Strategy classes - naming conventions and style?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class which uses the Strategy pattern to format names, based on a session setting:

```
String outputName = session.getNameFormatStrategy().format(name);
```

Now I find that I want to configure the object so that it either gets the name formatting strategy from the session (as above) or from another source. It seems like this is another good fit for the Strategy pattern:

```
String outputName = nameFormatStrategyStrategy.getNameFormatStrategy().format(name);
```

Where nameFormatStrategyStrategy might be, for example `RetrieveNameFormatStrategyFromSessionStrategy`, `StaticNameFormatStrategyStrategy`, `RetrieveNameFormatStrategyFromSystemConfigStrategy`.

Hierarchical structures and layered abstraction are good, but I really don't like `NameFormatStrategyStrategy`, and of course it could get worse with more layers.

Can I fix this with a better naming style? Or with another pattern?

Answer (score 4):

Having a `Strategy` for a `Strategy` seems like over-doing it a little bit. It seems like you have one `Strategy` that then has three ways of being defined - consider using inheritance in order to subclass into the three variations from a parent `Strategy` instead of using the nesting model.

In short, favor inheritance in these situations if you need to manage duplicate code - this would ensure that everything stays extensible without introducing a naming nightmare.

In my eyes, formatting a name from session is a single strategy that shouldn't be nested. Likewise for the other two listed cases.

EDIT:

Thinking about it a little more, you could do something like the following:

```
public class NameFormatter {

    public void setStrategy(NameFormatStrategy strategy) {
        // Set the strategy.
    }

    public String format(String name) {
        // Format according to set strategy.
    }

    }
}
```

This way, you could conceivably get rid of the nesting entirely and have a formatting class that lets itself be configured with one of the strategies (from session, etc.)

Comment: First of all, +1 for the last idea. I agree with you that because the name formatting problem seems to be getting out of hand so it should be encapsulated into it own unit, hence `NameFormatter`. This gives great flexibility because it allows you to inject strategies using a DI container and makes testing easier, and it could grow to use the Decorator pattern going ahead and you can benefit from the Abstract Factory to in the future. Overall if I could give you two up votes for isolating the `NameTransformer` I would definitely do but unfortunately I can't :) but really nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd update with what I eventually did.

I hid the nesting from the classes using the strategy API.

In addition to my original two Strategies `StandardNameFormatStrategy` and `FancyNameFormatStrategy` I added a `SessionConfiguredNameFormatStrategy` like this:

```
 public class SessionConfiguredNameFormatStrategy {

      private Session session; 

      public SessionConfiguredNameFormatStrategy(Session session) {
          this.session = session;
      }

      public String format(String name) {
          return session.getNameFormatStrategy().format(name);
      }

 }
```

I'm folding the "choosing which strategy" bit into a Strategy object, so the caller doesn't need to know about that extra level of indirection.

Pretty happy with it. I ended up removing code from the caller because it was no longer needed, and ended up with imports that were no longer needed - always a warm and fuzzy sign.